# Поехала таблица EmberJS

Tags: html, вёрстка, ember.js

Добрый день вывожу таблицу пользователей в Ember
Делаю вот так

```
<table class="strip-table users">
    <col width="25%"/>
    <cols></cols>
    <col width="20%"/>
    <col width="25%"/>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th><div {{!class="sortable down"}}>Name</div></th>
        <th><div {{!class="sortable up"}}>Email</div></th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Zip Code</th>
        <th>Children</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tbody>
      {{#each model as |user|}}
        {{ partial 'app/users/-user' }}
      {{/each}}

      </tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

В app/users/-user

```
<tr>
<td>
    <div class="user-info">
        <div class="user-photo">
          {{#if user.avatar_url }}
              <img src=""
                   title="{{ user.full_name }}"
                   alt="{{ user.full_name }}"
                   style="height: 100%;"/>
          {{/if}}
        </div>
        <div class="user-info-inner">
            <div>{{!<a href="#">}}test{{!</a>}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
<td>{{user.full_name}}</td>
<td>{{user.phone}}</td>
<td>{{user.email}}</td>
<td>{{user.postal}}</td>
<td>{{user.children}}</td>
<td>{{user.gender}}</td>
```

а на выходе

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Причем столбцы есть в -user просто сильно сжатые

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ощющения что они в один th все встали

Answer (score 1):

```
<tbody>
      <tbody>
      {{#each model as |user|}}
        {{ partial 'app/users/-user' }}
      {{/each}}

      </tbody>
    </tbody>
```

tbody внутри tbody в итоге все падало в перый th
невнимательно перенес код с другого проекта